# How to print keys from all key-value pairs

Tags: bash

Text file looks like this:

```
key11=val1|key12=val2|key13=val3
key21=val1|key22=val2|key23=val3
```

How can I extract keys so that:

```
key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23
```

I have tried unsuccessfully :

```
awk '{ gsub(/[^[|]=]+=/,"") }1' file.txt
```

gives back the actual data:

```
key11=val1|key12=val2|key13=val3
key21=val1|key22=val2|key23=val3
```

Comment: `awk '{gsub("=[^|]*","")}1'`

Comment: pluse-uno for data, required output and code! Keep posting!

Comment: This worked 100%
My output is :
key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23

Comment: Thanks Mr. Pursell !

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
while IFS='=|' read -ra words; do
    n=${#words[@]}
    for ((i=1; i<n; i+=2)); do
        unset words[i]
    done
    ( IFS='|'; echo "${words[*]}" )
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

#### sed

I did this with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/([[:alnum:]]*)=[[:alnum:]]*/\1/g' < file.txt
```

tested here and got:

```
key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23
```

`s/<pattern>/<subst>/` means "replace `<pattern>` by `<subst>`", and with the `g` in the end it will do it for every pattern found in the line.

The `[[:alnum:]]*` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z]*`, and means any number of letters or digits.

The first pattern between parentesis will correspond to `\1` in the substitution, the second `\2` and so on.

So, it will match every "key=value" and replace it by "key".

Comment: @babaji what results are you getting? Here I am getting this:
 ```
$ cat file.txt\n
key11=val1|key12=val2|key13=val3\n
key21=val1|key22=val2|key23=val3\n
$ sed -r 's/([[:alnum:]]*)=[[:alnum:]]*/\1/g' < file.txt\n
key11|key12|key13\n
key21|key22|key23\n
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution

```
echo "key11=val1|key12=val2|key13=val3" \
| awk -F'[=|]' '{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
    printf("%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1))?"|":"") 
  }
  print""
}'
```

**output**

```
key11|key12|key13
```

It should also work by passing in the filename as an argument to `awk`, i.e.

```
awk -F'[=|]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1))?"|":"") }print""}' file1 [file_more_as_will_fit]
```

---

Discussion

We use a multiple character value for FS (FieldSeperator) so each `=` and `|` char mark the beginning of a new field.

```
-F'[=|]'
```

Because we know we want to start with field1 for output and skip every other field, we use

```
for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)
```

`printf` formats the output as defined by the format string `'%s%s'` . There area a zillion options available for `printf` format strs, but you only need the value for `$i` (the looping value that generates the key) and whether to print a `|` char or not.

```
printf("%s%s", $i ...)
```

And we use `awk`'s ternary operator, which evaluates what element number is being processed `(i<..)`. As long as it is not the 2nd to last field, the `|` char is emitted.

```
(i<(NF-1))?"|":""
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

#### gawk

This can be done by `awk`, by setting `FS` and `OFS` :

```
kent$  awk -F'=[^|]*' -v OFS="" '$1=$1' file
key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23
```

or safer: `awk -F.... '{$1=$1}1' file`

#### substitution (by sed for example):

```
kent$  sed 's/=[^|]*//g' file
key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[=|]' '{print $1,$3,$5}' OFS="|" file

key11|key12|key13
key21|key22|key23
```